# Zip ActiveX with PPMd on X64

Tags: activex, zip, 64-bit

Is there a Zip ActiveX control that supports PPMd compression on X64? Looked at several options but couldn't find one that meets this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at Bricolsoft Zip Activex:
http://www.bricolsoft.com/zip-activex-component.html

It supports PPMd, LZMA, BZip2 and deflate on both X86 and X64. Also supports other bells and whistles such as multithreading, AES encryption, self-extract:
http://www.bricolsoft.com/zip-activex-features.html